# Info: Contacted by spammers (Ispirer Systems) referencing Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, spam

Not sure if anyone else got this, but I found the following in my mailbox:

> Hi, Peter!
>
> My name is [removed], and I’m Sales & Marketing Manager in
>   Ispirer Systems. I found your contacts on stackoverflow.com. We are
>   impressed with your activity on this website. Our company would
>   appreciate if you could help us to promote our tool and services on
>   it.
>
> We would be grateful if you could post a few answers mentioning our
>   company’s name, tool or services. Can this collaboration be
>   interesting to you? Under what conditions would you agree to do this?
>
> I look forward to your reply.

Note: I noticed that the mail address used was lifted from my website, and is different from the one I used at SO, so I have no reason to believe that those details got compromised in any way.

I'm not interested in adding spam to the site, but hopefully someone could alert the powers that be about these kind of schemes being pulled.

Comment: Did this come via SO Careers may be?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Highly doubt it. This was an effort from someone to lift my mail address of my website, possibly just targeting people with recent activity on SO. I'm pretty confident I'm not the only one who got this.

Comment: [You're not the only one to have received this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242350/can-should-we-report-companies-who-solicit-astroturfing-services).

Comment: Note that if you had turned this around and asked a question about "Which companies are trying to persuade users to promote their products" and named Ispirer Systems in an *answer*, they "would be grateful".  I guess for some companies there's no such thing as bad publicity (or else Meta posts like this are better publicity than what they conventionally receive).

Comment: So, does this mean you're *not* interesting in collaborating with us? Signed, Mr. Spammer

Comment: It's like soliciting product placement. "I can answer this, but first, I need some `coca cola` to go with my `little debbie's oatmeal pie`. (BTW. dont you hate when the cream filling gets on the genuine leather of your `new 2014 Lexus xxxx`?  I do!  It takes nearly half a bottle of `Armour Leather Care(TM)` to clean it off.) So, you asked about Integers..."

Comment: @BenVoigt - To avoid that I posted the mail in this way. I'm fine if this means the post eventually gets removed for not being a question. Mostly wanted to ensure it was known.

Comment: It didn't take me more than 10 seconds to find your address, phone number and email.  Maybe you shouldn't make it that easy.

Comment: On a side-note, this post is now on the first page of search results for Inspirer Systems ... All attention is good attention? :)

Comment: @HansPassant - I run a business. Hiding my details would not make much sense. The mail I received clearly references SO. I'm not worried about being contacted, I'm more concerned that apparently spammers are trying to have their wares peddled by approaching SO users through their profiles.

Comment: Boy, these winners sure are persistent. They must have started this after they realized the anti-spam system was blocking them from posting more from their location. We've been destroying dozens of their accounts over the years, and the last round should have outright blocked them for a while.

Comment: *[sends email, motivates meta post that drives traffic to website]*  -- Mission accomplished.

Comment: Wish someone would give them my email so I could get some of that sweet, sweet Ispirer cash.  Love it.  Just like I love the Ispirer FizgigWidget!  I use it every day to hurf all the durfs in my codebases.  Terrific!  Great job.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'll send them a big invoice.

Comment: How much are you earning from this Meta post? Confess! (;

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia http://www.quickmeme.com/img/5f/5f91584182fd7272b1f6b8647b40932691eb50fce4be09d0f5d9b3ad6f07a88f.jpg

Comment: And is http://www.ispirer.com/wiki/sqlways/teradata/data-types really the best reference link for Teradata data types?  I think http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1143_111A/ch04.043.034.html#ww18262798 is the official site?

Comment: There's still [a few links using ispirer as documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sqlways) which should be fixed up to point to official sources instead.

Comment: If you google for "Ispirer Systems", this meta post is on the first page. Well done everyone!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about partially accomplishing the mission of a spammer.

Comment: Depends on their "mission" and their "metrics".  Almost certainly, getting linked to from StackOverflow will slightly improve their Google rank; but at the same time, an article which criticizes them for being sleazebags in the top position of the Google search results is likely to deter the kinds of contacts they *ultimately* hope for.  Clicks != paying customers (unless you involve some sort of ad click scheme; and even then, if it isn't your primary source of revenue, probably still not worth it).

Comment: Can we find alternative sources for all sources now pointing to docs on that company's site? Please [check out this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A*ispirer.com*) and find alternative links for each of those hits. There are 15 posts as of this writing to be edited.

Comment: @lpapp: I can only talk for myself. What makes me upset is that they try to outsmart their customers, which shows how they think about them. And subverting a community is far from what I expect from a company I would deal with.

Comment: @lpapp: it became our problem when they tried to use Stack Overflow to lie to their potential customers. Stack Overflow is built on quality and trust, and lies like these undermine both quality and trust.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: shift+del is your friend. Do not get so much attached to such spammy emails. If I did that, I would go crazy in no time. It is not worth our time. I get several spam emails daily from everyone, including the Linux kernel mailing list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I'd be reluctant to literally remove every reference made to their site. I'll admit that I haven't checked their site, but going through that list, it does seem their wiki serves a purpose, by comparing specific datatypes across different platforms. If they did the research for this, and that content is their original work, that'd certainly be something I'd have no issue seeing on SO. Nor would I actually mind if someone points out that a specific tool of theirs would solve a particular issue I'd face. (Still not being paid by them!).

Comment: @SchmitzIT: sure, content is king; if their content is the better source, so be it.  I am just extremely distrustful of the company now, and if links can be replaced with similar or better sources, I'd rather we use those.

Answer (score 101):

There's no problem with anyone providing an honest-to-goodness testimonial for something that they've used, and feel confident recommending to someone else, provided that they're actually *answering* a question by doing so *and doing it in good faith*.

On Stack Overflow, questions that would invite this sort of thing are *rarely* asked in a manner that fits within our on-topic guidelines. This is part of the reason why we don't really entertain any kind of recommendation questions on a site that size - it's just too difficult to police.

We do thoroughly investigate abnormal numbers of links to something appearing in an odd period of time (quite easy to turn up, and Stack Overflow never sleeps). You could have 5k, 10k, 20k or even 350k - if we catch someone obviously astroturfing (for fun or profit) - mods won't hesitate to initiate a lengthy timed suspension or worse. It's *very* common for us to run queries on our live database while supporting moderators that are chasing down something that just doesn't smell right.

***If someone approaches you with an offer to plant links on our site, please [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and let us know***. We'd *much* rather reach out to an organization before it comes to this and help them understand our self-promotion guidelines.

The key things any company needs to pay attention to:

- Only a small percentage of your posts should promote your product (note, merely [supporting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) folks by answering programming questions *about* your product is not considered promotion, but don't 'seed' questions, the community will catch that quickly).
- You should establish yourself by providing useful answers that *don't* mention your product prior to doing anything else
- You should clearly disclose your affiliation with any product you mention in the course of making a recommendation to someone
- If asked to stop, ***stop***. You'll just have to live with the fact that you can't do what you want to do.
- Our advertising rates are quite reasonable. Did I mention that you should reach out to us?
- Continuing to try to link to your stuff after being asked to stop *can and will result in your developers not being able to use the site at all*. Don't do it.
- Never, ***ever*** create accounts for the sole purpose of elevating the posts left by other accounts. That's a great way to end up in our blacklist, so that *no one* can link to your site.

In fact, you're welcome to link to this answer should you receive anything like that in the future, after letting the other party know the account you've worked very hard at making shiny just isn't worth whatever they might be offering.

Comment: One of the (many) awesome things about Stack Overflow is just how naturally resistant to spam the platform has been, in spite of the popularity. No doubt a lot of that has been due to work by dev team, but it's still nice to have such a high confidence that a random post will be ham signal instead of spam noise.

Comment: @Tim Post There are some questions on SO like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392084/is-there-a-good-batch-migration-tool-for-migration-from-firebird-to-mysql, where the user just searches for a tool to use. As you can see other tools are mentioned there. However, according to the rules provided by you a company is not allowed to write about its tools or services here. Therefore it seems like compliance with the rules in this case does harm to the questions’ content and meaning. What is then a good and allowed answer to questions like this?

Comment: And to clarify the situation for those who first met our company name in this topic: We have never posted millions of answers. As far as we know the total amount of answers mentioning our company has never exceeded a few dozen (and all of them were in relevant topics).

Comment: @IspirerSQLWays You've personally contacted Stack Overflow users and asked the to advertise your product here. That's one. Second, questions seeking for tools are off-topic on [so]. Third, it's perfectly fine to post an answer containing your product if **and only if**: You specifically say that it is your product, and you are affiliated with it, **and** it provides real value to the answer, and you aren't just forcing your product on the answer. Look at your answer below. It didn't accumulate that many downvotes for nothing. I suggest you take this and think well where and how you want to ad.