# Should hovering over 'faded' answers re-style them for improved readability?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

When an answer post receives a certain number of downvotes (I think it's -3) then the post is re-styled to become "faded". I understand that this is of benefit to take focus away from the so called "bad answers", which I am fine with.

However, there are many instances where it is still desirable to read these posts, and although I am still able to do so, it certainly makes it more hmmm... 'awkward' to read them.

My suggestion would be that when the user hovers over the post, then the style reverts to the standard "black font" style, which enables the post to be easily read.

This would also be applicable to the comments that are faded. Note that there is already a hover style on the comments for the background color.

There are a few good example [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210/what-non-programming-books-should-programmers-read/278879#278879).

Comment: I usually highlight the text to increase readability by a tiny bit but it's still very hard to read. Faded color is nice to deemphazie the importance of the post but when you still want read it, it shouldn't be made harder than necessary. Hover effects may increase attention unnecessarily though. Maybe change the style only when interacting with the post or clicking on the text?

Comment: @kapep: Yeah, I did consider that situation, but I struggled to find a scenario where it would actually bother me if I accidentally hovered over one and it became more readable. I always sort posts by votes, and if I scroll to the bottom of the barrel I know to expect bad answers, personally the vote score is already obvious enough for me that I don't even benefit from the fade in the first place (but I can still see the potential benefits for other users). The 'click' suggestion is fine, but does require pre-knowledge of it... I imagine most users wouldn't instinctively click a text-only post

Comment: Here's an even better idea, don't fade it at all - I've always found this to be odd and annoying.

Comment: Yeah it would be more like a hidden feature then. It could help new users who don't look at scores much, so the effect doesn't make the post catch their attention too much.

Comment: @kapep And that would have the benefit of working on touch screens where the hover functionality is all unavailable.

Comment: Considering that the community has expressed their discontent for the answer you're trying to read, should you feel that sense of awkwardness when trying to read it?  We're warning you, this isn't something you want to really follow; it's even made less visible to make it less apparent to you.

Comment: @Makoto: There are other reasons to read an answer other than wanting to use what is suggested. You might want to read it so to offer a suggestion on how it should be improved, or because somebody has replied on a comment you left a year ago and you want to make sense of everything (which is what happened to me the other day)

Comment: This feature request is completed. Please mark this as status completed. Refer this for more infro :- http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296505/is-there-a-way-to-temporarily-un-gray-posts-grayed-out-by-down-votes

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName I just noticed it for the first time today, and I must say I like it a lot.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure that there's some reason why they haven't done this (and I'm pretty sure that this is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find the original).

However, in the meantime, I've written [a quick little userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/5003/unhide-downvoted-answers) that does what you've described.

[image: Demonstration]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is by design or bug, but anyway, greying out was removed for answers with the launch of the new design, as I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update/277221#277221) (point 2).

MSO earlier greyed out answers with <-7 score, but no longer does, as can be seen [there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/info-contacted-by-spammers-ispirer-systems-referencing-stack-overflow/274959#274959), for example. As it is planned to restyle SO as well, I guess it will behave similarly.

Comment: All things considered, reducing the gray-out threshold to -7 wasn't a bad idea, considering how dynamic and different votes on Meta tend to be.  But, how do we know that this is going to carry to the main site?  I'd legitimately expect that it won't, since there are downvoted answers in questions that one may consider actively harmful.

Answer (score 2):

Good idea. Based on suggestions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296505/is-there-a-way-to-temporarily-un-gray-posts-grayed-out-by-down-votes/298818?noredirect=1#comment253793_298818), we've made the answers 'unfade' on hover.