# Is there a way to temporarily un-gray posts grayed out by down-votes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design, low-quality-posts

My eyes are not all that great, I have issues distinguishing certain colors/brightness, it is not that I cannot read them, it is just that is really hard.
As consequence I find it very hard to read the content of grayed out posts.

I think it is useful to have them grayed out because their content is likely not so useful, but, what if you want to read them?

Is there a way to turn off the grayed out color on those posts, other than messing with the styles/html with some developer tool? I was wondering if there is maybe a button or something you can press or hover over to get it temporaly back to the normal color while you read it.

**UPDATE**

I checked on SO Tavern about the best way to proceed. I have tagged this question as feature request and restated the desired behavior bellow.

**I think it would be very useful for people like me, with eyesight issues, to have a way to temporarily un-gray these posts and other places (such us ignored tags) to be able to read them comfortably without struggling.**

Two possible ways of achieving this are either by removing the grayed out when the user hover over the post with his mouse or with a button.

Comment: Currently, there is not a way to do this on site. Your only option is indeed to mess around with the styles/html. I'm sure, though, a userscript could be made to add a button to un-gray a post.

Comment: A userscript that changes the style to a high-contrast style would be a great idea…

Comment: This isn't a big deal with one line non-answers, but it's especially annoying when reading long answers that are well-written but unpopular (which occur fairly regularly on meta).

Comment: There is a feature-request of this somewhere in MSO, IIRC.. But I can't seem to find it. The closest I could find is http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252175/293416 . Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129593/293416

Comment: I have noticed that the Stack Overflow background colors looks very different on different monitors until I adjust the monitor to my taste. Perhaps you can improve your reading experience by tweaking the contrast and brightness of your monitor?

Comment: @MartinLiversage - That would affect other sites, but it could be used as a momentary adjustment, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @CoolGuy - Thanks for the links, I also searched and didn't find, but sometimes I forget to jump to meta, I was surprised I couldn't find anything.

Comment: On a post by post basis, you can click to edit. The preview is not greyed.

Comment: Windows: Control+A. / Mac: Command+A. / Tablet: Long press text to select.

Comment: Should this be posted (or retagged, respectively) as feature-request on MSE or MSO if it cannot be found on either?

Comment: @JonasWielicki - I can do whatever is more appropriate.

Comment: Returning contrast to normal on hover would be a **great** feature-request.

Comment: This is a great feature-request and we've now implemented returning contrast to normal on hover. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Could you please post your comment as an answer instead being buried in the comments?

Comment: @NathanOliver sure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a great feature-request, so we've now implemented returning contrast to normal on hover. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: Could you also get someone to mark the other post as `status-completed` too? Thanks. And thank you for the implementation, I like the way it slowly drifts back to normal.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for reminding me. The post is marked.

Answer (score 142):

No there isn't a way to un-gray a post, unless you use some developer tool.

But you are raising a good point here:

> My eyes are not all that great, I have issues distinguishing certain
>   colors/brightness, it is not that I cannot read them, it is just that
>   is really hard. As consequence I find it very hard to read the content
>   of grayed out posts.

This means IMO that SO should be pay attention to accessibility and run some tests on the site.

One of the tests to pass the [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) is the [Contrast](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/#qr-visual-audio-contrast-contrast), which probably the grayed posts aren't passing this specific test.

So, again IMO, either there is a change in how grayed posts are shown or that "switch button" is created.

Comment: Same issue with selecting '[ignored tags as grayed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283869/1070452) in preferences

Comment: @Plutonix - I agree with you, I find all those things really hard to read. Although when is a small amount of text, is relatively easier.

Comment: It would be nice if it un-greyed on mouse over. Obviously wouldn't work if js was disabled.

Comment: :hover CSS as in misterManSam's answer doesn't look half bad. Could have a tag above the answer like '**Low-voted answer**: some StackOverflow users did not find this answer useful.' as a cue that the no-longer-grey hovered text is still iffy. Might be generally useful for someone's first sighitng of an answer like that anyway.

Comment: As a visually-impaired user, I concur.  I'm getting sick of every site I use going for 'stylish' colour schemes that absolutely impact the basic functionality of a site.  It's a horrid, designer-led, trend that needs to stop.  It's about time accessibility was taken seriously, and not left as a 'nice-to-have'.

Comment: I agree. This site provides a simple test for the "gold standard" Web Content Accessibility Guidelines with foreground and background inputs http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/ For the lighter part of the grayed text it gives a contrast of `1.27:1` which fails the test. A 4.5:1 ratio is the minimum requirement.

Comment: I think that SO should take a lead and tackle accessibility (WCAG) with some priority. It's a case where some leadership should be taken as it's never going to win any user popularity contest but it is insanely valuable to those who need it.

Comment: I have now selected Kurtis as the answer, since they have implemented the request.

Comment: @Dzyann no worries my friend. It is more than understandable

Answer (score 75):

Here is a super simple style that will fade the post back to normal when it is hovered. It's using the same selectors that are used to change the opacity and can be easily applied with your favourite User Styles manager such as [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/).

[Here is a packaged user style I prepared earlier](https://userstyles.org/styles/115016/show-faded-stackoverflow-answers-on-hover).

The style:

```
/*Transition to full opacity over .3 seconds*/
.downvoted-answer .post-text,
.downvoted-answer .post-signature,
.downvoted-answer .comments,
.downvoted-answer .vote>* {
    transition:opacity .3s
}
/*Full opacity please!*/
.downvoted-answer:hover .post-text,
.downvoted-answer:hover .post-signature,
.downvoted-answer:hover .comments,
.downvoted-answer:hover .vote>* {
    opacity:1
}
```

Comment: That is very useful, I will take it into account in my home computer, however It won't work in all devices.

Comment: This should be the norm here. On mobile, it should be on tap.

Comment: After reading the question, I was going to scroll through to make sure no one made a userstyle before make one for OP, +1 :)

Comment: @LeoNatan It could be jarring for people who use the mouse wheel to scroll and who want to ignore the greyed-out answers. Perhaps use an animation to add a brief delay?

Comment: you need to add semi-colons after each css rule

Comment: @cornonthecob https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax#CSS_declaration_blocks

Comment: @misterManSam yes that's true - it's just a good idea to put them there in case you need to put more rules in the block

Answer (score 23):

As a workaround, you may select the text (possibly pressing Ctrl+A to select all). Depending your OS theme, it will have a better contrast (light gray on washed blue on my system -- but YMMV).

Comment: I do that sometimes,  but I was hoping there was something already implemented, I think it is important to have site accessible for everyone, I am probably not the only one with not so good eyes, heh.

Comment: @Dzyann I agree: accessibility is a _must_. I've only posted that as an answer (instead of a comment) in order to make it more visible to future visitors having the same issue.

Comment: Yes it can be useful!

Comment: then copy and paste in a text editor.

Comment: @1010: That is not accessibility, that is an annoying workaround. On top of that, you lose helpful formatting and context. I believe OP is looking for a long-term solution that benefits the entire community.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I agree. but select all alone isn't more readable than grayed text.

Comment: Note that *light gray on washed blue* is OS and theme dependent. I get white on purple, for instance. Many high contrast themes exist for most operating systems.

Comment: @nico Correct. I've slightly edit my answer to reflect that.