# Un-gray questions in review queues when hovering over them

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, design

Since we now are [returning a post to normal highlighting when hovering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296505/is-there-a-way-to-temporarily-un-gray-posts-grayed-out-by-down-votes) can we implement this in the review queues as well.  For myself it is not too bad but it still strains the eyes trying to read the attached question when it is grayed out.  This would improve accessibility and make reviewing easier.

[image]

Comment: When is the question greyed out?

Comment: @TylerH I added a screen shot to show the question being "grayed out"

Comment: Okay, so this would only be relevant for answer review queues. I was confused since I spend most of my queue time in the question queues.

Comment: @TylerH Yes this is only relevant when the review serves up an answer and attaches the question underneath in a grayed out tone.