# Why are questions in review queues grayed out?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

For example, in low quality posts, https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27049109 has the pale gray question.

How is one supposed to review whether an answer is of low quality without reading the question?

[Un-gray questions in review queues when hovering over them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300766/un-gray-questions-in-review-queues-when-hovering-over-them) requested ungraying on hover (and also provides a screenshot of the current UI), I take it this was never done. As I understand it it is *expected* that the person reading the review queue would read the question, hence graying the question out to me seems inappropriate.

Comment: Duplicate of [Un-gray questions in review queues when hovering over them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300766/un-gray-questions-in-review-queues-when-hovering-over-them)

Comment: [My userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReviewQueueHelper.user.js) increases the opacity of the question from 60% to 80%, and full opacity on hover.

Comment: Thank you for the userscript. My goal with this question was to get the site to behave more sensibly out of the box. Perhaps a futile effort.