# Coworker asking another coworker to vote all his questions and answers to gain points. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, voting-fraud

They are doing it all day and I can see it. Is this behaviour reportable?

Comment: I can see and hear them from my seat which is the back of their desks asking favor to vote each other with stackoverflow page opened. And one of the guys asked me long time ago to do the same thing for him when we were in the same team but I declined.

Comment: Ah, so you're talking about your own coworkers... I had suspected that when I read your question. I'll post an answer. I wonder if we should get your name removed from this meta post since you have posted here and we'd hate to see you get into trouble for doing the right thing.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes. I would be happy if you can remove my name.

Comment: Great, I've contacted the community team to get this done for you.

Comment: I wish this were less prevalent than it obviously is. I'll see a question, see a rubbish answer to it (vague, incomplete, sometimes outright wrong) and it immediately gains 3-4 upvotes in the space of seconds. ***sigh*** One can only hope that clean living wins out in the end.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that there's a possibility that your coworkers may fall foul of the serial upvoting rules that SO has in place. The exact algorithm behind it is not public, but you may be doing them a favour by stopping it from happening.

Comment: I can’t believe some people find Stack Overflow reputation that important they feel the need to “cheat” in order to inflate it. Why? Do they get a pay rise if they have a higher S.O. rep?

Comment: @BoltClock what happened to removing this user from the post? Is that actually possible / going to happen? .... and so it just happened...

Comment: @Cayce K: *Just* happened as you were typing your comment. SE employees need to sleep too you know ;)

Comment: @BoltClock that type of thing happens to me a lot... but yay for the user!

Comment: His name's still on the meta post though; it's just greyed out.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: That's not the OP's user name - anon is simply the placeholder that's left after the question's *anon*ymized.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, I see.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I seem to believe that's rather just people who are just like "I don't know the answer to this." or maybe just "This is indeed a question." and then "This answer sounds like it might possibly be useful to someone, maybe." or maybe just "Oh, an answer, let's upvote it." as opposed to voting rings. I've spent a lot of time on this site (not as much as you, though...) and I see it happen all over the place, all the time (and I've certainly posted a few answers myself which got a few upvotes in the first minute or so, and I don't seem to remember joining a voting ring).

Comment: @Dukeling: *"and I've certainly posted a few answers myself which got a few upvotes in the first minute or so, and I don't seem to remember joining a voting ring"* LOL! Yes, there's also people upvoting (or downvoting) what they don't understand. A separate problem. (Of course, I'm sure your answers got upvoted because they were correct, clear, and useful. I'm talking about voting on *other* answers. Not yours. Or mine. :-) )

Comment: There is always the possibility that OP is just annoyed that he isn't getting the upvotes, and the reason he isn't is because his co-workers are actually judging posts on quality before voting and OP doesn't have any quality posts which is why the co-workers refuse to boost his rep. I would validate OP's posts to see if this is plausible but no link so can't. I just hope the co-workers are not punished if they haven't actually done anything wrong. I am against the serial voting rule, but I know it probably does more good than it does damage as I have no doubt there are farmers out there

Comment: Oh @musefan, such a cynic! :)

Comment: Related: the same situation from another viewpoint: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138517/how-to-vote-on-friends-colleagues-questions-or-answers

Comment: Why was my comment deleted?

Comment: @musefan As BoltClock's answer says, they will *investigate* and take action *if there's evidence*. No one is going to take action against the users in question without looking for evidence.

Comment: @jpmc26: And what evidence will there be? If they see USER A has upvoted USER B a lot, how will they know if it was done blindly or based on quality of answer? Will they really review all the posts that have been voted, what if they don't understand the subject area. I am sure it's more likely the right outcome will occur, but it cannot be guaranteed for sure

Comment: @musefan: In vote fraud cases, usually those users only / mostly vote for each other.

Comment: I'm disappointed that I don't have co-workers to engage in this kind of scam with. It had never occurred to me. It's almost worth getting a job just for this. Okay, no it isn't.

Comment: @MartinBean http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#work-compensation-so

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Whether you are referring to

1. a group of users you don't know, whom you have witnessed conspiring in public and/or suspect to be coworkers or otherwise related to one another based on their user profiles, or
2. your own coworkers in that you're witnessing this behavior in your very own workplace,

this behavior is considered fraudulent and is entirely reportable. Simply flag any post belonging to one of the suspected users for ♦ moderator attention and explain the situation. We will investigate and take action if we do find evidence that the users have engaged in voting fraud.

In the particular case of #2, you don't have to worry about being found out, as your flags (including your name) can only be seen by moderators and Stack Exchange employees, and will never be revealed to anyone else.

Comment: But what if person-A is asking/answering legit questions/answers and also gaining votes from other users including from person-B who is helping person-A? Person-B have the rights to vote if the A's question/answer is legit. There is no evidence or anything. What would happen?

Comment: If the posts are legit (i.e. they're OK in quality, not spam, and not plagiarized from elsewhere) we'll leave them. If other unrelated users are voting on their posts, that's fine too. Voting only becomes a problem between a group of users if their votes are being concentrated on one another and not on other people's posts, intentionally or not. The action we take usually only entails invalidating those votes and sending a message to each user involved to let them know that voting should be based on content and not biased towards specific users.

Comment: SO has system in place that detects such behavior. Coworker in my previous company used to do it for few days and when they got caught by SO, they lost earned reputation that way. It all came to light when they got caught and one of the coworker made it public.

Comment: @BoltClock Riddle me this. I and a bunch of my colleagues try to stay somewhat active on SO. We have each others profile links and often see what the other person is upto and upvote their questions/answers where we feel appropriate or publicly/privately ask them to edit their answers where we think they are incorrect. I think this should be ok.

Comment: @BoltClock I acknowledge that it's simply not possible for SO to automatically judge whether the votes were casted honestly or 'claw me claw thee'. And the needs of many outweigh the needs of few. But it should at least clearly stated so, don't you think?

Comment: @iosDev82: That's great! You're peer-reviewing each other's answers and encouraging one another to correct mistakes. I encourage you to do the same with others on the site. Many voting rings involve people blindly voting for one another thinking their coworkers are infallible.

Comment: @iosDev82: As long as you make sure you're not voting on each other's answers *at the expense of others* (which is a little hard when you're educating and helping one another), you're good.

Comment: @BoltClock thank you for your very eloquent answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: Your answer reads a lot more harshly than your comments. Your answer seems to imply it's totally fraudulent whereas your comments seem to imply it's only fraudulent if the posts are spam/bad quality... I'm not sure which one you're really arguing for, but I'm against the first one and for the second one myself.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The vast majority of these cases are blatant attempts at gaming the system. iosDev82's is quite frankly a special case and one I wasn't expecting to address here at all until they commented. If you come to SO with the mindset of helping people, you're probably not going to "conspire" or make an agreement to only ever upvote each other's posts and skew the system unfairly for everyone.

Comment: @BoltClock: I see. Just to give you another example, in a handful of instances in the past, I've upvoted my peers' questions just for the sake of either encouraging them to post more, or to give them enough rep for the commenting privilege, which they were finding quite stupid and which I agreed with. I would have not otherwise seen the questions myself, and even if I had, I would not have voted on them at all, since they were completely typical questions -- neither particularly good nor bad. Now did I "game" the system here? Yeah I think I did. Was it the wrong thing to do? I didn't think so.

Comment: *"your flags (including your name) can only be seen by moderators and Stack Exchange employees"* **plot twist:** OP works for Stack Exchange

Comment: @iosDev82 I have had rep stripped from your exact situation. SO did not care that the q's & a's were legit. SO did not care that I had votes from many others. SO did not care that my colleagues voted on many others. SO just said that since 'Bob' had voted on some of my posts, that it was fraudulent. So BoltClock's comments may be his impression, but that is not how it works in reality.

Comment: @Mehrdad I would be very careful about doing this. This is not (in reality) allowed by the system. The process of being accused of cheating is not a pleasant one, and allows absolutely NO leave for recourse.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Yeah pretty much same thing has happened here as well. And I don't mind. It is simply not possible for SO to judge whether upvotes were legit or result of 'ring of upvoters'. And the whole SO has to be bigger than the upvotes I get. :D

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: Oh I've been careful about it all right. I've been active on SO for > 4 years and I'm pretty sure I can count on *one* hand the number of times I've done something like this. In the most recent case I remember, I just didn't see a better solution: my peer was trying to post a comment, but couldn't because he didn't have enough rep. His only recourse was to post an answer (which it wasn't) or to ask a duplicate question (which was also stupid). What was he supposed to do? The most logical solution I could think of was to give him a couple upvotes to allow him to comment...

Comment: @Richard Le Mesurier: If SO didn't care that the posts were legit, they would have removed the posts outright. But I'm surprised your response never got a follow-up - though I don't know all the specifics of your situation. If you want I can give the staff a poke.

Comment: @Mehrdad this is wrong. You are voting for the *person* not the *post* whereas is should be the other way round. Why was your peer trying to post a comment? Was it really necessary to post that comment? The answer your question "What was he supposed to do?" is that they should go off and look for something else they *can* answer without commenting and earn reputation that way.

Comment: @BoltClock The posts are undeniably legit, as were the votes gained from colleagues and strangers. "Recourse" involved me being stonewalled and further accused. And the thing is, its not about the unicorn coins, its about the actual rep: we were guilty without any way to prove innocence. And I now can't ever vote on their posts no matter how brilliant they may ever be. That part of the system is totally wrong.

Comment: @ChrisF: It was as necessary as pretty much any other comment I've seen on SO. He had the exact same question as the one that was in front of him, but the answer under it didn't work the way it claimed to work. If you think a comment was unnecessary there then I'm not sure what you think they're for; you might as well disable commenting. As for just going off and looking for something else: you do realize that's much easier said than done, right? Especially for a beginner? And that merely answering something else doesn't mean someone will see/upvote their answer in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: @ChrisF: Keep in mind, for a user new to SO, he *was* already doing a hell of a lot of things ***right***: he had already found the duplicate to his question, he already knew he wasn't supposed to post an answer, his questions were already of acceptable quality, etc... yet he still couldn't get his question answered. You've ***got*** to realize the system is imperfect when people who *don't* go through the trouble of learning the system end up getting what they want more efficiently than those who do (e.g. by posting dupes or posting comments as answers).

Comment: @Mehrdad OK - I'll admit that this is the problematic case. I don't know what the answer is though. Allowing unfettered commenting isn't going to happen without major changes to how we moderate comments for spam etc.

Comment: @Mehrdad - the only solution you have **is** to ask a new question but a) link to the one you've already found and b) state clearly that none of the answers work and c) phrase the question as "I found this answer, but it doesn't work", explaining exactly what you expect and what the results actually are. This might work, but does still run the risk of getting closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yeah, I agree; that's the other solution. I've tried it before; sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Same with comments. In my experience, when the question is obscure, commenting works far better, since it's directly targeting someone who knows about the problem. For basic questions asking again works better. I don't think there's a perfect solution either; the only reason I brought it up was to point out that the incentives don't always work in favor of of the ideal user, and hence occasionally the system can benefit from being "nudged" in an otherwise-"fraudulent" way.

Comment: @Mehrdad wonder if you considered pointing them to [25 posts worth editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164035/165773)

Comment: @gnat: You're joking, right? Tell him to find 25 posts to edit *and wait for the rep for all of those to accumulate* before being able to address his own problem? Even *I* couldn't find 25 posts worth editing in a reasonable amount of time, never mind having the patience to wait for all of them afterward before I can address my own problem...

Answer (score 16):

Well, the fact that they shared what they are doing (on purpose or not) made them fall from the horse because, unfortunately, that behaviour happens all around:

- Users that know each other personally;
- Users that know each other from Stack Overflow; (as long as the question/answer isn't completely off - same for the above point)
- Users that don't like someone upvote the competition and downvote their targets;
- Users that answer and downvote all other answers on the post;
- etc., etc.;

That's a common practice. Not long ago someone I know was on Stack Overflow and I was behind him, we were both checking the answers to a question we had interest in, and when he saw one from Jon Skeet he said, "*this guy is king!*" and upvoted. There was an accepted answer that wasn't Skeet's, but Skeet's got his upvote just for being Skeet's.

Such behaviours are practically impossible to detect, but once detected, what you did is the right thing, because as a pattern behaviour, it can be identified and "*taken care of*".

Comment: The people getting outraged about this are guilty of exactly the same thing as the people doing it: taking a number in a database too seriously.

Comment: @jwg: Site rules are site rules. You break'm, you face the consequences. Simple as that. I'd love to see you tell a banker he's taking a number in a database too seriously.

Comment: @jwg, it's a matter of making the site a better one. Rep points are indicators that should mean something. I partially agree with you as I see myself not caring for users getting rep _irregularly_. It's up to users to be biased by rep points in questions/answers, I chose not to. Furthermore, the rep points definition should inform that they really are indicators but can also be deceiving, as points may be obtained in several ways, including editing a post. As for Cerbrus' comment, that doesn't apply, you're talking apples and oranges

Comment: Regarding the Skeet-related behaviour, that's really quite dumb as Skeet is "king" largely through precisely such actions. I'd expect better from a programmer who ought to have just a modicum of logical common sense. But, I suppose, we cannot get away from the fact that some people are simply stupid...

Comment: Exactly @LightnessRacesinOrbit, that's my point. In a perfect world, the voting would be perfect. And you put your finger exactly on the wound by saying "_Skeet is "king" largely through precisely such actions_". The majority of the rep points that very high rep users have comes from there: I see answers that are correct, well structured and correct with dozens of upvotes because of the author, you can find perfect alternatives on the same post, sometimes previous to theirs, much less upvoted. **NOTE** _this fits Skeet **and** other very high rep users, nothing against Skeet at all_

Comment: @chiapa: Yep.​​

Comment: With the whole 'high rep' users debate, a good example of that I have personally been involved in: A high rep user posts an answer quickly after the question is asked, they get upvotes almost instantly, I pointed out in comment the answer was wrong (did address the issue), high-rep users says "ah yes, my mistake" and deletes the answer. perfect example that people upvote based on rep, and don't stop to read or validate the actual content of the post

Comment: @musefan,it may be the upvote was based on clearly written easy to understand answer.   (Regardless of the answers correctness).

Comment: @IanRingrose: It's a nice excuse, but is that a valid reason to upvote? Should an incorrect answer ever be upvoted based just on how good it looks? What if it's not even on the same subject, but it looks the dogs? I am not sure that counts. and then also, why only high-rep users pull off good looking answers...

Comment: @musefan,  Cleanly not, but the person up-voting may not know it is incorrect.       Having a lot of rep seem to mostly be related to how QUICKLY someone that write LOTS of CLEAR answers.   (Skeet seems to get most of his rep from answers with only 1 or 2 up votes.)

Comment: @IanRingrose: well then high-rep users need to start learning to prioritize accuracy over speed. Not to mention how many get around the issue by quickly posting one-liners and then editing them to actually make them good quality.. they still get the upvotes from the one-liners though before they have even made the edits. I think the fact is people feel more compelled to factor rep into their voting decisions. They see rep as an unquestionable reflection of a person's knowledge, they cannot comprehend that a high-rep user may actually post an incorrect answer so they don't bother to validate

Comment: @IanRingrose: And lets be honest, if the person voting doesn't have enough knowledge to be able to work out if it's right or not then they shouldn't cast a vote anyway. But it's a cascading effect, one dimwit upvotes and then the rest upvote because "hey, it's already got an upvote, it must be right"

Comment: Jon Skeet is always right. Even when he copies someone else's answer. :-)

Answer (score 12):

This is fraud.  Outright fraud.  Their behavior is unacceptable and they should be severely reprimanded.  Alert the local authorities and optionally Stack Overflow moderators and hopefully the appropriate action will be taken.  What nerve.

Comment: *You have earned the* ***Torches and Pitchforks*** *badge. See* [***your profile***](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4343502/jay-frizzle?tab=badges).

Comment: Call your local police detachment! There must be something they can do about voting fraud... on a question and answer site...

Comment: I'm 100% serial about this.  It's dishonest and deceitful and for all we know they're probably commiting more heinous crimes as well.

Comment: Yeah, but... voting rules on this site are not within the jurisdiction of your "*local authorities*"

Comment: Maybe you should [edit] your answer to correct that misconception.

Comment: I'm upvoting this purely to game the system and "undo" the downvotes. This is gold. Someone sue me!

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm calling the local authorities to report you right now.

Comment: I'm disappointed to see that there isn't actually a ***Torches and Pitchforks*** badge.

Comment: @KenY-N: Feature request! Just gotta think of something to award it for.

Comment: Oh my god it's the rozzers

Comment: looking at +11/-11 vote split, I bet that if I vote this up to +1, someone else will come and vote it down back to 0. And if I vote down to -1, someone will vote it up back to 0. Now _that's_ a voting fraud, I refuse to participate in this

Comment: @gnat: Upvotes are winning. You can vote, now.

Comment: @Cerbrus that has to be some voting ring at work. I am calling local authorities to investigate and round up the usual suspects

Comment: There ain't no voting cartel here! You have no evidence!

Comment: I voted up this. I know Jay Frizzle. He is one of my co-answerer. And I'm requesting others to share my comment and upvote this comment :P Arrest me I say.

Comment: Shhh, don't tell them!  You're going to get us both in trouble

Answer (score 6):

Voting based purely on somebody asking you to do so is in no doubt wrong, and if you spot it (or know of it from other sources) then you should act. @Boltclock provides an excellent answer on this already, in that you should flag one of the voted posts for moderator attention and explain the situation for them to review.

However, you should also be aware (IIRC) that raising invalid flags can result in a penalty to you (though I don't know what that is off the top of my head). So to this end you need to be sure that the behavior you are reporting actually does break the rules. For example:

Asking a friend or co-worker to 'review' your posts isn't a problem. As long as those people apply the same standard of reviewing as they would with any other post - by any other user - when they decide whether to place their vote or not.

Now although my opinion isn't written anywhere officially on SO that it's acceptable to do that, consider the fact that SO does promote sharing posts on social media sites. In reality, if I was to share one of my answers on Facebook for example, it is no different than sharing it with a co-worker. We are reliant on those viewing our posts to do the right thing, regardless of how they came to find the post.

Finally, I just want to stress that I am not in anyway condoning blind voted just because someone you know asked you to do so. But please take care to ensure you are certain that a user is being fraudulent, as it could result in the mods misjudging (as they are humans too) and users could end up losing a lot of rep that was validly earned, which isn't fair either.

Comment: The penalty for having more than 10% of your flags in the last week marked declined is an automatic warning; 25% causes a flag-ban, which I believe increases in duration every time you trigger it. Worst case, barring deliberate attempts to abuse flagging to cause trouble, the only penalty flagging idiotically will land you with is the inability to flag anything.

Comment: Or you can just create a new account when your old one gets question-banned.  Use your old one to upvote the new one, post a few bogus answers that just copies the accepted answer, you're back in business in 10 minutes or less.  And no, you can't ask a question about it, best to keep it a secret that only banned users know about.

Answer (score -16):

There is a real issue with this, people in (or from) some part of the world consider that their co-workers, friends and families have a **duty** to promote what they do regardless of how good it is.

It is call **being loyal** and is considered a **social duty**.

(The same issue happens with references, with friends and families expected to provide good employment and landlord references regardless of the truth.)

***So are we going to limit StackOverflow to the part of the world that put “3rd party rules” above personal relationships?***  Otherwise to we just give up on voting and rep being meaningful?

Comment: To put in blunt... those parts of the world (wherever they may be) are wrong. Being a good friend (or whatever) is about being there to guide them down the best path. Sometimes that means to say your idea is bad, and this is why.

Comment: To turn your questions around, are we supposed to give up on any site goals that conflict with someone's culture, somewhere? I feel like you're letting the perfect be the enemy of the good here. Encouraging people to be fair and honest probably won't be an affront to people's values that drives them away from the site. And the question of if StackOverflow's reputation model works or not doesn't boil down to "do people have different cultures?". If you have specific data that StackOverflow "isn't working" and a specific fix in mind, make a post about that.

Comment: If a culture's ideas on criticism are getting in the way of actually solving real technical problems robustly, that culture needs to very seriously consider modifying those ideas. Respect is great, but "works in the real world" is even better.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I have seen it with my own eyes. Culture often can and does hinder a person achieving success. That's hard to imagine for some but it can be viciously true. If corruption is part of the culture, should we excuse it? I say no! Part of fighting corruption is defining it. This question is a perfect example of an attempt at defining corruption.

Comment: I might also mention that corruption ideas are not simply rules foisted on third world countries. The locals are sick of it too. I know because I live in such a place (not in the USA). So don't use culture as a reason to lower standards. Rather we should maintain our principles. The best way for a highly corrupt country to achieve success is to fight corruption.

Comment: well said, Ian. I would say that if the post is wrong, the friend's duty is to downvote. But overall, I agree that a friend's duty / colleague's duty is to engage at the very least. SO does not allow colleagues to engage on each others' posts no matter how good the quality is. I believe that is wrong and hypocritical.

Comment: Gaming the system and playing favorites knows no national or geographic boundaries. They are universal problems.

Answer (score -154):

That's perfectly fine if the answer is right and is not of poor quality.

It's the same as if you would share your answers/questions on Facebook, Twitter or G+ for which there are explicit share buttons.

Comment: _Sharing_ is fine. _Asking for upvotes_ on every single answer / question you post, however, isn't.

Comment: Sharing is asking for upvotes.

Comment: _"Hey buddy, look at this, what do you think?"_  is the same as _"Please upvote this!"_? I don't think so.

Comment: Of course, that's the whole point of social media.

Comment: SO isn't Facebook. SO is a Q/A site with as main goal to provide quality questions / answers. Sharing with the sole intention of getting "likes" is no more than vote fraud.

Comment: The difference is that Facebook likes aren't supposed to indicate quality (in fact quite often they indicate the opposite, that what you see is base, lowest common denominator stuff), whereas SO votes are. That you get reputation as a result is secondary, the most important thing is that the higher quality questions are voted up.

Comment: ...and anyone who shares his/her own question with the sole intention of getting upvotes (as opposed to getting answers, which would be the whole point of asking questions) deserves neither.

Comment: Frankly, it's disappointing that someone with 10k rep doesn't see the difference.

Comment: *"Of course, that's the whole point of social media."* I disagree with your answer, but that comment made me laugh. :-) Excellent commentary on social media.

Comment: Almost 30 downvotes in less than 20 minutes, impressive!

Comment: @Cerbrus I see the difference. Still, I have a more pessimistic view on people's (voting) behaviour.

Comment: @DavidG People must have shared it with their coworkers to downvote it :D

Comment: @DavidG Well, this Meta Question was also linked in SO, so more people will notice this question and these answers.

Comment: Most users don't blindly upvote every single link they're fed. In fact, I've seen plenty of shared links backfire, when shared with reasonably experienced SO users.

Comment: *32 downvotes in just 28 mins... time is running behind the downvotes... seeing this first time in life...*

Comment: @inf "I have a more pessimistic view on people's (voting) behaviour" Then perhaps the difference you've failed to grasp is between what you perceive as commonly happening, and what is considered a Good Thing. "That's perfectly fine" is a very different sentiment than "that's very common, but strongly discouraged".

Comment: @IMSoP That's right, but as long as the share buttons are there I think that any other form of sharing shouldn't be penalised.

Comment: The difference between social media followers and people who will upvote everything you share is that you don't usually have an agreement with your social media followers that they'll upvote everything you share or post regardless of its actual quality (unless your name is Justin Bieber maybe, and even then the "agreement" is mostly a one-sided affair).

Comment: @inf You can share anyone's post, not just your own; and you can vote up, down, or ignore any post, whether it's written by your friend or not. And voting is not another form of sharing - which posts you've voted on isn't public information. So I don't really see the contradiction in encouraging sharing but discouraging arbitrary voting.

Comment: @IMSoP That's a good point. I agree with that. However, I don't think that the voting is arbitrary if the answer has the required quality. I will add that last part to my answer.

Comment: If it helps you understand why sharing your Q or A for upvotes is bad, then maybe it would help to remember that other people are gonna reference your Q and A. A newbie doesn't know if your answer is good or bad, likewise your question. When you popularity vote the quality drops and it affects people negatively when they reference SO.

Comment: @JohnSnow I fully understand and totally agree with you. I just think that you can not promote sharing on proper answers on the one side and disallow voting cycles on proper questions on the other side as both have the same effect of popularity voting instead of quality voting.

Comment: Do you still not see the difference between asking people to just look at the post (And provide feedback) and explicitly asking someone to upvote the post? Sure, sharing will get you views, but views don't guarantee upvotes. A deal with a friend / colleague to upvote each other's posts on the other hand, is vote fraud.

Comment: @Cerbrus If I would ask somebody to upvote my post I would of course assume that they read what they post and tell me if it's wrong. The same way if I shared my post and asked somebody for feedback I would expect him to upvote my post if it's ok.

Comment: You're aware this question is about users playing the system by upvoting each other's posts, right? They don't care if their posts are low quality. They just upvote them because they're friends.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't see that anywhere in the question and I don't want to allege somebody of doing something without proven so I gave an alternative view point.

Comment: It's in the ___title___ of the question: _"Coworker asking another coworker to vote all his questions and answers **to gain points.**"_

Comment: @Cerbrus Now you highlighted the "to gain points" not where it says that they don't evaluate what they read before upvoting. Gaining points is totally fine, that's what we have them for after all.

Comment: And did you read the comments? How is it unclear that this question is about users playing the system? _"Asking <...> vote all <...> to gain points"_

Comment: In the comments that I see, maybe some got deleted out of privacy reasons, it only says that they ask each other to vote on each other posts but not that they do it blindly.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not facebook, what's the point of doing so ? do you feel comfortable with a fake score?

Comment: >implying Facebook likes are any more material than Stack Overflow rep

Comment: If you share on social media, votes would (theoretically) be indicative of usefulness (although perhaps that's usefulness in quantity more than quality, which is not ideal, but at least it's still usefulness). If you ask your friend to upvote all your stuff, he's more likely than not just going to upvote everything or things that look like they **could** be useful, but aren't actually / particularly useful.

Comment: @inf who needs comments, the title of this question is pretty self-explanatory ;) Congratulations on >100 downvotes.

Comment: @inf _it only says that they ask each other to vote on each other posts but not that they do it blindly_ Maybe it doesn't explicitly say they do it blindly and I agree that it would have been better if it did. However that was largely and very obviously implied. Explicitly specifying that would only have served the purpose of preventing people from pretending not to know that this is about blindly upvoting. Haven't you really even had the doubt ? If you didn't, I find that strange. If you did, I would have asked for that to be clarified instead of just assuming this wasn't about blind voting.

Comment: -119 - that is, in a morbidly somewhat sad way, impressive...

Comment: @SantiBailors That's right. We should have done that in the beginning.

Comment: @santiago Thanks, however I probably have to delete and put it to and end  as people now start to revenge downvote me on SO proper.

Comment: You've gotten 2 downvotes over a timespan of about 30 minutes. I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: @inf meta effect?

Comment: @inf May be you should ask the community team to get your name removed? :D

Comment: @MinNaingOo: But then inf couldn't claim ownership of the most downvoted answer on SO, should it come to that.

Comment: @Cerbrus Haha, who is leading in that list currently?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites

Comment: All these downvotes are just from users who lack the ability of logical thought. They stopped when they read "fine" with no consideration that you are limiting it to certain conditions. Then you probably have a lot of users that stopped reading when they read the number of downvotes and just downvoted based on that. Completely agree you should be able to get people you are know to review all your questions as long as they vote on normal voting standards. At no point have you said it is ok to blindly vote... which ironically is what all these downvotes seems to have done

Comment: oh and it's also funny that if you look at the comments for BoltClocks answer, (which everyone seems to love). BoltClock is basically agreeing with you by saying it's ok as long as the posts are reviewed on their quality, and not just upvoted based on the user.

Comment: @musefan: All of those downvotes are because this answer is totally missing the point of the _question_, which you seem to be missing, too. This _question_ is about 2 people that know each other sharing the answers with the explicit intention to _upvote each other to get more rep_. This answer says that that is _"okay"_, which it really isn't.

Comment: @inf: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/info-contacted-by-spammers-ispirer-systems-referencing-stack-overflow/274959#274959

Comment: @Cerbrus: First off, this is a discussion, so I think it's ok to post answers that offer opinions. But the question doesn't explicitly say they are blindly voting each other, nor does it offer any proof (which lets be honest would be hard to provide). This answer is merely offering a situation where it might be acceptable to do so. The OP can consider this reason and they may decide actually, my co-workers are validating and quality checking all the posts before they vote. Point is, people are downvoting this answer because they don't agree that there is ever a valid situation to do it

Comment: @musefan: FWIW, the first 40 or so downvotes were when this answer did, in its original revision, stop at "fine". Can't speak for the other 80 but it's unlikely all 40 of the initial downvoters will care let alone reevaluate their votes. Also, that's the whole point - if you're voting based on the user, it's wrong, if you're voting based on quality, then presumably it doesn't matter to you whom you are voting for in the first place. The fact that the two coworkers in question are colluding with one another "to get points" suggests they're not above that.

Comment: @musefan [The question _does_ say that it's about 2 guys playing the system.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299841/coworker-asking-another-coworker-to-vote-all-his-questions-and-answers-to-gain-p/299861?noredirect=1#comment223821_299861)

Comment: @BoltClock: Good point about the edit, I did miss that factor. I can accept downvotes based on that.

Comment: @Cerbrus: In what land would you expect any normal conversation to involve somebody saying "get points"? It is highly unlikely that was actually said. So we can assume OP is telling us his version of what was said, thus we cannot know for sure if OP hasn't misunderstood what was said. So the situation is 2 people may or may not be breaking the rules. This answer explains an instance where it wouldn't class as breaking the rules. Just like BoltClock is offerent an example of when it does break the rules (and takes that further to explain what to do in that case, which is good)

Comment: @musefan: [_"And one of the guys asked me long time ago to do the same thing for him when we were in the same team but I declined."_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299841/coworker-asking-another-coworker-to-vote-all-his-questions-and-answers-to-gain-p#comment223594_299841) I'm pretty sure the OP understood the intentions of his co-workers just fine. As I keep repeating: __The question is about 2 people playing the system.__ _"That's perfectly fine"_ is _never_ a good answer.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh snap, that score will be hard to crack.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Lets just forget it, I concede that the pre-edit version wasn't *as* acceptable as this version. And because of that it's difficult to even guess why the downvotes exist... is it because people think it's a bad answer, or did they jump on with the people who downvoted the original version just 'cus.

Comment: I've never seen ___140___ _"just because"_ downvotes.

Comment: @Cerbrus: But what if you have 'never seen it' because you don't recognize it when it happens? How can you be sure this isn't 140 downvotes 'just because'? I don't think it can be argued that there are plenty of people in this world that make decisions just to fit in with the crowd, would it really be so unreasonable to think that it could be the same with SO users? People have a need to be part of what is popular, and even though we don't know who these 'popular' people are because votes are anonymous, they still know they are part of it and sometimes thats enough for them

Comment: I think it's _extremely_ unreasonable to assume _that many_ people didn't read the question / answer and just blindly downvoted this answer.

Comment: I think its *extremely* **likely** to assume **most of these** people blindly downvoted this answer. @Cerbrus, that is how voting works on SO. Just ask the Jon Skeet fanclub

Comment: You made the list of meta's most downvoted answers: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/36658/most-down-voted-answers