# What to do with a tag which might have been created for promotional purposes?

Tags: discussion, tags, spam

Earlier today a question was asked about [open-liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-liberty). Two questions have tagged with so far. There are some peculiarities:

- Both appear to be off-topic ([first Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46301208) looks like a recommendation request; the [2nd Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46306036) isn't a clear programming question either)
- Both are also asked and answered by IBM employees who work on the Websphere Liberty team.

To me this seems like a marketing tactic, which might be considered as spam. Any thoughts about how to deal with this?

---

Related question: [*Coworker asking another coworker to vote all his questions and answers to gain points. What should I do?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299841)

Comment: Let's assume good faith and hope that someone from the CM team will reach out to them?  I see little for us to really take action on.

Comment: I'm willing to assume good faith, but all three are members of the community for at least two years. They should know how SO works by now imho.

Comment: Again, **good faith**.  Flag a moderator, point 'em to this question, and ask that they either look into the situation to see if it warrants someone from the CM team to reach out.

Comment: Indeed, mod-flagging probably would have been gentler than releasing The Horde upon them. Both questions got several quick downvotes and the first has since been closed and deleted.

Comment: @AndrewMyers:  %:s/probably would have been gentler/would be more constructive/g

Comment: @Makoto Thx. Flagged a question for moderator attention with a link to this Q.

Comment: hi there, to attempt to set the story straight, we have a piece of software (WebSphere Liberty) that we are contributing the core of to open source, so today was genuinely the first day of a new piece of software.  Perhaps they are better suited for another SO domain?  For my question (2nd one) we do get users confused with these sorts of things and it was my attempt to set the story straight.

Comment: @AndyGuibert "What is this product and what are its features" is indeed an important pair of questions for a product to answer, but SO isn't the place to answer them.  Better would be that product's webpage.

Comment: Hi, the intent was not for marketing purposes. I did a search on stackoverflow and there are a load of similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=where+can+I+find+the+source+code+for so I assumed the question was a reasonable one. It is one I have been asked several times. As noted in the answer if these questions will get deleted so will the tag which would be a shame.

Comment: @Alasdair that search reveals a lot of old questions, some with downvotes, some closed, most badly asked. I guess moderation has gotten more strict over the years. Anyway, a question that can be solved with a quick google is not a good one, and since you guys did make the site findable, it's already a bad question because of that, even if it would be on-topic (which it isn't in my opinion).

Comment: Looking at existing questions is not a good way to figure out what is or is not on-topic here. A better way is to consult the Help Center, specifically [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), where you would find out that *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* So, questions asking for someone to locate source code are almost certainly off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the questions are deleted, then the tag will automatically be deleted as well.  If the questions aren't deleted, and are worth keeping around, then it seems entirely appropriate for a tag describing the topic they're asking about to exist.